# Computer boots to black PXE screen, then reports "no bootable device"

Tags: windows-7, boot, hard-drive-failure

When I turn on my computer, I get the following on a black screen:

```
Intel UNDI, PXE-2.1 (build 082)
Copyright (C) 1997-2000 Intel Corporation
For Atheros PCIE Ethernet Controller v2.0.0.4 (03/03/09)
PXE-E51 : No DHCP or proxyDHCP of fers were received.
PXE-MOF : Exiting PXE ROM.
NO BOOTABLE DEVICE -- insert boot disk and press any key
```

This message then repeats itself several times.

Why is this happening, and what can I do about it?

Comment: PXE boot is enabled in the bios, enter the bios and disable it.

Comment: `NO BOOTABLE DEVICE`. The hard drive has probably failed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Computer doesn't boot up, shows PXE error and/or "operating system not found", "no bootable device", "insert boot media", or other similar error](https://superuser.com/questions/1219285/computer-doesnt-boot-up-shows-pxe-error-and-or-operating-system-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

#### By default, most computers are configured to use [PXE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment) as a final boot option after the hard drive. If you're seeing this, this means that your computer can't see the hard drive. This usually means that the drive has failed.

- If the computer can't see a hard drive or other device to boot from, it falls back to PXE booting, which will fail in the absence of a PXE server (very rare outside of a business environment). The computer finds that it has no device to boot from, and therefore displays a `NO BOOTABLE DEVICE` message.
- A failed hard drive typically will not communicate with the computer, causing it to disappear from the system. Repetitive buzzing, clicking, or beeping noises are the most common indication of a hard drive failure. **See: [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inacessible-data-from-my-storage-device)**
- If the drive isn't doing anything at all (not spinning up or making any noises), it may be disconnected from the computer. If this is the case, try opening the computer and reseating the drive or its cables.